# PDO prepared statements in pgsql vs mysql

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, pdo

I'd like to know why there's a different behavior between PDO drivers `pgsql` and `mysql` regarding prepared statements (`PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false`).

To demonstrate what I mean, I have prepared two equivalent queries (one for `pgsql`, one for `mysql`) and a PHP Unit test case.

The following queries, where the table *intendedly* doesn't exist, produce the following errors:

---

**pgsql**:

```sql
INSERT INTO "addresss" SELECT * FROM "address" WHERE "id" = 80
```

`SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 FEHLER:  Relation »addresss« existiert nicht`

---

**mysql**:

```sql
INSERT INTO `addresss` SELECT * FROM `address` WHERE `id` = 80
```

`SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'addresss' doesn't exist`

---

Here's the test case:

```php
try
{
    $stmt = self::$connection->getPdo()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch (\PDOException $exception){
    echo $exception->getMessage();
}
```

In case of `mysql` the exception is already thrown on `getPdo()->prepare($sql)`, but in case of `pgsql` it is only thrown on `$stmt->execute()`.

Why do I know that? Because, when I omit `$stmt->execute()` and run the test case for `pgsql`, the test succeeds. But it still fails for `mysql`.

- Why is that?
- Is it possible that `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false` does not work for `pgsql` same as for `mysql`? Because when I set it to `true`, I suddenly have the same behavior for `mysql`, that the exception is only thrown on execution not on preparation.
- Can I force somehow with a certain setting, that PDO throws an error already on preparing the statement with `pgsql` as it does with `mysql`?

Comment: Well, pgsql is for PostgresSQL, mysql is for MySQL. So you need to use the driver for whichever database you're actually using.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Maybe OP speaks Parseltongue.

Comment: Did you guys even read or understand my question? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Had a look in the [source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo_pgsql/pgsql_statement.c) code of the PDO pgsql driver and it appears that it postpones the prepare to the first execute as per comment in the source:

```
/* we deferred the prepare until now, because we didn't  
 * know anything about the parameter types; now we do */
```

Comment: Great, someone who understood my question :) Your catch is very interesting... I guess it is due to the datatype strictness of pg?

Comment: Yes the prepare statement in postgresql requires a list of types.